# Как реализовать паттерн Одиночка?

Tags: c#, объекты, наследование, шаблоны-проектирования

Необходимо было с помощью паттерна Фасад посчитать страховой взнос за недвижимость. Классы : квартира, таун-хаус, коттедж. Параметры: срок страхования, жилплощадь (м2 ), число проживающих, год постройки здания, износ здания (%). Фасад я реализовала, как здесь реализовать паттерн Одиночка?

```
    namespace Facad
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Flat flat = new Flat();
            Town_House town_h = new Town_House();
            Cottage cott = new Cottage();
 
            HouseFacade ide = new HouseFacade(flat, town_h, cott);
 
            Person person = new Person();
            person.StartApplication(ide);
 
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
 
    class Flat : House
    {
        public void Vznos(int srok_straxovania, int summ_straxovania)
        {
            double vznos;
            vznos = (summ_straxovania * 0.45 * srok_straxovania);
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма страхования {0}, срок страхования {1}, cтраховой взнос для квартиры составляет: {2}", srok_straxovania, summ_straxovania, vznos);
        }
        public void Information(int square, int count, int data, byte iznos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Информация о квартире: жилплощадь = {0}, число проживающих = {1}, год постройки = {2}, износ здания = {3}%", square, count, data, iznos);
        }
    }
    class Town_House : House
    {
        public void Vznos(int srok_straxovania, int summ_straxovania)
        {
            double vznos;
            vznos = (summ_straxovania * 0.45 * srok_straxovania);
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма страхования {0}, срок страхования {1}, cтраховой взнос для таун-хауса составляет: {2}", srok_straxovania, summ_straxovania, vznos);
        }
        public void Information(int square, int count, int data, byte iznos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Информация о таун-хаусе: жилплощадь = {0}, число проживающих = {1}, год постройки = {2}, износ здания = {3}%", square, count, data, iznos);
        }
    }
    class Cottage : House
    {
        public void Vznos(int srok_straxovania, int summ_straxovania)
        {
            double vznos;
            vznos = (summ_straxovania * 0.45 * srok_straxovania);
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма страхования {0}, срок страхования {1}, cтраховой взнос для коттеджа составляет: {2}", srok_straxovania, summ_straxovania, vznos);
        }
        public void Information(int square, int count, int data, byte iznos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Информация о коттедже: жилплощадь = {0}, число проживающих = {1}, год постройки = {2}, износ здания = {3}%", square, count, data, iznos);
        }
    }
 
    class HouseFacade
    {
        Flat flat;
        Town_House town_house;
        Cottage cottage;
 
        public HouseFacade(Flat flat, Town_House town_h, Cottage cott)
        {
            this.flat = flat;
            this.town_house = town_h;
            this.cottage = cott;
        }
        public void OpenVznos()
        {
            flat.Vznos(3000, 1);
            town_house.Vznos(5000, 2);
            cottage.Vznos(6500, 2);
        }
        public void OpenInformation()
        {
            flat.Information(54, 3, 1994, 56);
            town_house.Information(89, 5, 2009, 30);
            cottage.Information(98, 4, 2017, 12);
        }      
    } 
 
        class Person
        {
            public void StartApplication(HouseFacade facade)
            {
                facade.OpenVznos();
                facade.OpenInformation();
            }
        }
 
        interface House
        {
 
             void Vznos(int srok_straxovania, int summ_straxovania);
             void Information(int square, int count, int data, byte iznos);
        }
}
```

Comment: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) - несколько версий на любой вкус.

Comment: Причём я бы реализовал самым очевидным - через статическое поле, ибо явно учебная задача и вряд ли нужна потокобезопасность. Да и насколько я видел, как мэтры бьются над этими одиночками там весьма нетривиально если делать все по уму.

Comment: @AK статический конструктор вызывается один раз, это гарантировано платформой, поэтому это решение потокобезопасно. Если инициализация объекта лёгкая, то именно так и надо делать, это самое простое решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу правильного проектирования синглтона есть довольно известная [статья Джона Скита](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton).

Самый простой из правильных методов в этой статье — такой:

```
public sealed class C
{
    static readonly Lazy<C> lazyInstance = new Lazy<C>(() => new C());
    public static C Instance => lazy.Value;
    private C() { }
    // тут остальные поля и методы
}
```